# TypeError: chatHub is undefined in Signalr

Tags: visual-studio-2010, signalr

I am new to `Signalr` and I am trying to make 'one to one chat' application. I have defined chat connection using below code :

```
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
```

And its related methods are in `ChatHub.cs` file. Don't know why it is showing error `TypeError: chatHub is undefined`. Please help me to solve this.
I am using `Signalr 1.0` with `Visual Studio 2010`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use `SignalR` 1.0?

Comment: @Matei_Radu, No, I tried 2.2.0 but getting same error.

Comment: It is not because of this, you should get back to `2.2.0`. Now, could  you provide the entire client code? (Also, enable detailed  errors in `Startup.cs` and add this line on the client, before starting the connection:
`$.connection.hub.logging = true;`

Comment: I am using 'Visual Studio 2010' so `Startup.cs` not possible.

Comment: Ok, please provide the client connection code

Comment: Are you sure you can use SignalR without aN Owin Startup class? This might be the issue. You are not registering SignalR to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Startup` class even if you don't have the template available, just add a new class and paste the code.

If you insist on using `Visual Studio 2010`, please [have a look at this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581909/GettingplusSignalR-ReadyplusinplusVisualplusStudio).

Hope this helps, even though this question would have been more explicit if the client code for connection was provided, as I kindly asked you in the comments.

Best of luck!